# sorting and getting uniques

Tags: vb.net

i have a string that looks like this

"apples,fish,oranges,bananas,fish"

i want to be able to sort this list and get only the uniques. how do i do it in vb.net? please provide code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using LINQ, like this:

```
Dim input = "apples,fish,oranges,bananas,fish"
Dim strings = input.Split(","c).Distinct().OrderBy(Function(s) s)
```

Answer (score 6):

A lot of your questions are quite basic, so rather than providing the code I'm going to provide the thought process and let you learn from implementing it.

Firstly, you have a string that contains multiple items separated by commas, so you're going to need to split the string at the commas to get a list. You can use [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) for that.

You can then use some of the extension methods for `IEnumerable<T>` to filter and order the list. The ones to look at are [Enumerable.Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx) and [Enumerable.OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx). You can either write these as normal methods, or use Linq syntax.

If you need to get it back into a comma-separated string, then you'll need to re-join the strings using the [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join.aspx) method. Note that this needs an array so [Enumerable.ToArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx) will be useful in conjunction.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a VB.NET programmer, but I can give you a suggestion:

1. Split the string into an array
2. Create a second array
3. Cycle through the first array, adding any value that is not in the second.

Upon completion, your second array will have only unique values.

Comment: And you can use VB.Net's Array.Sort to sort the final array; and use the Join(array, delimiter) method to convert back to a string, if necessary.